# Using UIGradientLayer as layer.mask to fade out bottom / top of a scrollview --> repositioning of mask is lagging behind

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a subclass of UIScrollView which should be faded out at top / bottom.
(From opaque to clearColor, like the Notes.app does at the bottom of the DetailView.)

So I added a UIGradientLayer as scrollview.layer.mask which seemed to work fine until I scrolled the first time:

```
    CAGradientLayer *mask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    mask.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9],
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                      nil];

    mask.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                   (__bridge id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                   nil];

    mask.frame = self.scrollview.bounds;
    // vertical direction
    mask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
    mask.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);

    self.scrollview.layer.mask = mask;
```

But when I scrolled, the mask scrolled with the content instead of sticking on the screen position to fade out the content nicely.

I kind of fixed that by reposition the mask in the scrollviews layoutSubviews:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect layerMaskFrame = self.layer.mask.frame;
    layerMaskFrame.origin = [self convertPoint:self.bounds.origin toView:self];

    self.layer.mask.frame = layerMaskFrame;
}
```

But now the movement of the mask is kind of delayed when I scroll.
It looks like the frame of the mask is set with a delay and animated.

Both, the scrolling and the movement of the mask ist smooth, so I don't think it's a problem with too slow hardware.

But how can that be? layoutSubviews shouldn't be called from a animation, and I set the new frame immediately there...

Comment: as fas as I know `layoutSubviews` *is* called when you scroll a `UIScrollView`. I'd lay another `UIView` containing only the gradient behind a the `UIScrollView` and make the `UIScrollView` transparent.

Comment: The problem is, that the scrollview itself has to be masked out, as I want to fade out the content, not adding a gradient background.

Comment: So do as I said and put the gradient view in the foreground, but disable user interaction to let the touches reach the scroll view below.

Comment: Ok, that would be an idea ;) 

But everything is in a transparent popover, so a fake gradient above will not work in this case.

So I'm afraid using a layer mask is the only possibility

Comment: What about adding a sublayer instead of a subview?

Comment: even that Giulio's answer solved it, which subview do you mean, the whole scrollview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to this article http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html you have to surround your frame changes like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

// Set the frame

[CATransaction commit];
```

With this it should happen without any animations. Hope this works :)